# Forwarding Output of server which doesnt have xserver to my x client

Tags: ssh, x11, xorg, x-server

I have a digital ocean server which doesnt contain xorg is that possible that i can connect through ssh but for example editing etc output to my own editor or open links through in my browser etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Xorg on server you can't initiate -X forwarding from your client.

If you are interested in editing files, the easiest way is to mount the server to your local computer using `sshfs(1)`. You can consult manual page for more info about this.